# CRUD generation with composite key on Doctrine 2.2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, crud, composite-key

I got a problem with the CRUD generation on Doctrine. I saw that the composite keys have been implemented since version 2.1. I got a few tables that are identified with such keys but when I try to generate the code with the command php app/console generate:doctrine:crud it send me back the following error: "The CRUD generator does not support entity classes with multiple primary keys." 
Should I code my CRUD from scratch or is there a workaround to generate them?

Comment: I still don't know how to make a proper composite key on doctrine 2 but I used a "workaround". Instead of using composite keys, I used only primary keys to identify each row on a column, have added "unique: true" to the attribute where it made sens and modified a bit my db schema.

Comment: Where Doctrine can handle composite keys (such as having multiple @ORM\Id fields), it does not support the CRUD generation on it... In fact, MySQL does not support really well (on a self generated value perspective)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine doesnt support composite keys, you could just use a new primary key:

```
/**

 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hand ! :-) See my comment, it is what I've done and it worked perfectly! A friend told me it was actually not that bad for the overall database to have integer id as it could be better in terms of performance... and for sure a true time gain for some other more mind blowing tasks also!

By the way, as Talus said Doctrine does handle composite key since V2, it is just the crud generator that is not ok with that.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html